# Scraping data using Selenium and XPath C#

Tags: c#, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape data from this website

http://www.timgad-voyages.com/circuits/?ATV=1

I used Selenium and XPath to get data, this is the code:

```
public void scrape_timgad_voyage()
    {
        List<Tour> tours = new();
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.timgad-voyages.com/circuits/?ATV=1");
        var collection = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='iconbox iconbox-set-1b pl-none pr-none pt-sm mb-none']"));

        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            string title = item.FindElement(By.XPath("//h4[@class ='text-up hover-text-theme mb-xs mt-xs']")).Text;
            string duration = item.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='feature']/div/div[2]/div/div/a/div/div/div/div[2]/h4[3]")).Text;
            string img = item.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='feature']/div/div[2]/div/div/a/div/div/div/div[1]/div/img")).GetAttribute("src");
            string link = item.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='feature']/div/div[2]/div/div/a")).GetAttribute("href");
            
                Tour tour = new Tour()
                {
                    title = title,
                    duration = duration,
                    image = img,
                    link = link
                };
                tours.Add(tour);
        }
        foreach (Tour tour in tours)
        {
            _context.Tour.AddAsync(tour);
        }
        _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        OldTours.AddRange(tours);
    }
```

But this code scrape the data from the first Div only and repeat it 4 times. So what do i need to do to get data of the 4 Divs?

Answer (score 0):

Replace you foreach with this for loop, Your XPATH for each div is different & you have provided only one XPATH. Which is why you are always getting data for one div only.

```
    for(int i = 0; i <collection.Count-1; i++)
    {
    if(i == 0){
                string title = item.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='feature']/div/div[2]/div/div[i+1]/a/div/div/div/div[2]/h4[1]/b")).Text;
                string duration = item.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='feature']/div/div[2]/div/div[i+1]/a/div/div/div/div[2]/h4[3]")).Text;
                string img = item.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='feature']/div/div[2]/div/div[i+1]/a/div/div/div/div[1]/div/img")).GetAttribute("src");
                string link = item.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='feature']/div/div[2]/div/div[i+1]/a/div/div/div/div[2]/span")).GetAttribute("href");
    }
else{
                string title = item.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='feature']/div/div[2]/div/div[i+2]/a/div/div/div/div[2]/h4[1]/b")).Text;
                string duration = item.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='feature']/div/div[2]/div/div[i+2]/a/div/div/div/div[2]/h4[3]")).Text;
                string img = item.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='feature']/div/div[2]/div/div[i+2]/a/div/div/div/div[1]/div/img")).GetAttribute("src");
                string link = item.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='feature']/div/div[2]/div/div[i+2]/a/div/div/div/div[2]/span")).GetAttribute("href");
            i++;    
           }     
    }
```